# Why is the variable not defined?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I keep getting this error message: plate is not defined.

How do I fix this? And can I pls get an explanation why it doesn't work?

Sorry if this is really bad, it's my first time on stackoverflow.
Maybe you can give me some information how to ask better questions.

this is my code:

```
let A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, C1, C2, C3, C4, D1, D2, D3, D4;

A1 = [document.getElementById("A1"), true, 1];
A2 = [document.getElementById("A2"), true, 2];
A3 = [document.getElementById("A3"), true, 3];
A4 = [document.getElementById("A4"), true, 4];
B1 = [document.getElementById("B1"), true, 5];
B2 = [document.getElementById("B2"), true, 6];
B3 = [document.getElementById("B3"), true, 7];
B4 = [document.getElementById("B4"), true, 8];
C1 = [document.getElementById("C1"), true, 9];
C2 = [document.getElementById("C2"), true, 10];
C3 = [document.getElementById("C3"), true, 11];
C4 = [document.getElementById("C4"), true, 12];
D1 = [document.getElementById("D1"), true, 13];
D2 = [document.getElementById("D2"), true, 14];
D3 = [document.getElementById("D3"), true, 15];
D4 = [document.getElementById("D4"), true, 16];

setInterval(calculateplate, 1000);

function calculateplate() {
    let plate = null;
    let calculation = Math.floor((Math.random() * 16) + 1);
    if (calculation == 1){
        if (A1[1]) {
            plate = A1[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 2){
        if (A2[1]) {
            plate = A2[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 3){
        if (A3[1]) {
            plate = A3[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 4){
        if (A4[1]) {
            plate = A4[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 5){
        if (B1[1]) {
            plate = B1[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 6){
        if (B2[1]) {
            plate = B2[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 7){
        if (B3[1]) {
            plate = B3[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 8){
        if (B4[1]) {
            plate = B4[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 9){
        if (C1[1]) {
            plate = C1[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 10){
        if (C2[1]) {
            plate = C2[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 11){
        if (C3[1]) {
            plate = C3[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 12){
        if (C4[1]) {
            plate = C4[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 13){
        if (D1[1]) {
            plate = D1[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 14){
        if (D2[1]) {
            plate = D2[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 15){
        if (D3[1]) {
            plate = D3[0];
        }
    }
    else if (calculation == 16){
        if (D4[1]) {
            plate = D4[0];
        }
    }
    else calculateplate();
}
plate.innerHTML = 2;

console.log(plate);
```

I also tried with a switch() statement

Comment: put the last 2 lines inside the function.

Comment: The question should be self-contained and reproducible, so also provide the HTML code that this code is referring to (the elements `A1`, `A2` etc). It does not need to be the complete original page, but it should be sufficient to run this code without any errors other than the one that you ask about.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the plate variable outside the function.

You can't retrieve variables that are initialized inside functions. So your code could look like this.

```js
let A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, C1, C2, C3, C4, D1, D2, D3, D4;

//Code here

let plate = null;

function calculateplate() {
 
    //Code here
   }
```